# CREATE TABLE abc@gmail.com(..)

Tags: sql, oracle

How to Create a Table in Oracle with name abc@gmail.com

I tried doing CREATE TABLE abc@gmail.com(..)

but this gives me error so i was looking for some other way of doing it

Comment: Are you sure that creating a table per email address is the best solution to your problem? This sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: **Please don't do this, it will make all the rest of your code ugly.** Note, that if you do, when using the table, you will have to double quote the name, and the table name may be case sensitive. `select * from "abc@gmail.com"`. `select * from abc@gmail.com` will not work and `Select * from "ABC@GMAIL.COM"` may not work. Note also that, for Oracle, normally `@` indicates a linked server. So it will be confusing.

Comment: what would you select from this table, because you would have a table thats way to specific for multiple entities.

Comment: Yes, I'm honestly dying to know the proposed use case for this table.

Comment: Downvoted question because the answer requires a practice that is best avoided.

Comment: Also, without knowing the motivation for this question, note that Oracle has a 30 character limit on table names. Valid emails can be much larger than that. So if you are building a table per email address, um, that is not going to work in general.

Answer (score 4):

Either:

1. Put double-quotes around your table name:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE "abc@gmail.com" ...
   ```
2. Don't put special characters in your table names.

Future users of your database will thank you profusely if you choose option 2.

Comment: you actually are advising him to do this?

Comment: He asked the question. I answered the question. That's what Stack Overflow is for. I also gave him advice that doesn't really answer his question but makes for a better answer, as it speaks to best practices and avoids problems in the future.

Comment: We believe finding the **right** answer to your programming questions should be as easy as falling into the pit of success... you may technically be correct but we all know that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @Robert, don't forget that SO is used by others with similar problems looking for solutions. I think there's a consensus here that this is a bad idea *in this case*. That said, perhaps someone else would have a legitimate need to create a table with a special character in it's name? These answers would provide the solution, along with providing the advice to ask why such a solution is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I think is a **not good way** to place `@.` charactes in name of a table.

I think is a not good way to create each table per one email user. Propably **you have big database design problem** and you trying to find solution where it not exists.

Think about database `emails`, table `users` there each user have `unique ID` and `username` and `domain` in other column. On `ID` column you have create index, then you have some thing to find and add **relationship of user instance in other tables**.

Answer (score 2):

From http://ora-903.ora-code.com/:

> ORA-00903:    invalid table name
>
> Cause:    A
> table or cluster name is invalid or
> does not exist. This message is also
> issued if an invalid cluster name or
> no cluster name is specified in an
> ALTER CLUSTER or DROP CLUSTER
> statement.
>
> Action:    Check spelling. **A
> valid table name or cluster name must
> begin with a letter and may contain
> only alphanumeric characters and the
> special characters $, _, and #.** The
> name must be less than or equal to 30
> characters and cannot be a reserved
> word.

Martin and CanSpice have pointed out that it's technically possible, but, yeah... you're asking for plenty of trouble with this approach. And why (on earth) would you name a table after an email address in the first place? I'd be fascinated to know.

Answer (score 1):

To use non standard characters in identifiers you can delimit with double quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE "abc@gmail.com"(a int);
```

NB: Some of the discussion on this question reminded me of a [simple talk article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/laying-out-sql-code/). I just tested and this is possible in Oracle as well.

```
CREATE TABLE "╚╦╩╗" ( "└┬┴┐" nvarchar2(10));

INSERT  INTO "╚╦╩╗" VALUES ( '└┬┴┐' );

SELECT * FROM    "╚╦╩╗";
```

Note I am not suggesting that anybody actually does this.

Comment: you actually are advising him to do this? you should be ashamed that you have 19K...

Comment: @Robert - I'm not advising him either way. We know nothing about the motivation for the question and the other answers already had the admonitions angle covered.

Comment: Robert, what difference does it make, he needs a solution, I'm tired of people here with the response of "Why would you do that". You don't know why he is doing this, or what he is trying to accomplish in the big picture, just give him a hand instead of being a nay-sayer.

Comment: Thanks Martin really appreciate it.

Comment: @Joseph: Some people think that shooting themselves or others is a solution to their problems, but that doesn't mean it's wrong to advise against it.  Sometimes you just need to be told when you're being a dumb.ss.

Comment: @Joseph As Martin said, we don't know the motivation for the question, and that means a possible motivation for naming a table 'abc@gmail.com' is "unaware of the consequences". I'm not presuming that's the case, but nay-saying serves an important purpose when it is. To a newbie, there is value in a chorus of *"I wouldn't do that if I were you!"* :)

Comment: @duffymo, @djacobson, Ok fair points, I agree with you guys. I do however remember working for a huge corporation and having to solve ridiculous problems that only exist because the bureaucracy around me. Nonetheless, you guys are right, but at the end of the day it wouldn't have bugged me if he had offer a solution along with the criticism.

Answer (score 0):

What an odd name for a table.

I don't have access to an Oracle instance to find out which error you are getting, but it will refer to the third point below:

- The table name must begin with a letter.
- The table name can not be longer than 30 characters.
- The table name must be made up of alphanumeric characters or the following special characters: $, _, and #.
- The table name can not be a reserved word.

That email address looks like it should be **in** the table, as data.

Have a think about what you are going to store in the table and that should give you a more appropriate table name.

Answer (score 0):

If you must, you could always name the table "abc_at_gmail.com" and get on with it.

I believe the at-sign means "link to another database" in Oracle.  You're out of luck in preserving the e-mail address.

If you really need multiple e-mail addresses, why wouldn't you create a users table and have multiple rows, one per e-mail address, and make e-mail address a unique index on the table?  Your design idea must be breaking some normalization rule.